# Runtime error Launch timed out, workload was not healthy after 30 min. Getting this error on huggingface. Any suggestions?

Tags: huggingface

Runtime error
Launch timed out, workload was not healthy after 30 min. I am trying to deploy a model on Huggingface and getting this error. Any help will be appreciated

Manual upload model was what i did. Model works perfectly in local.